# override tostring of anonymous class

Tags: java, static, tostring, inner-classes, final

I want to override the title of each movie in a list.
I tried to make the `x` static and final but the compiler complains.

```
List<Movie> mList = new ArrayList<Movie>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
int x;
mList.add(new Movie(){


  toString(){

   // need an easy way to give a unique string to each movie here.
   return "Movie" + x;
  } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<Movie> mList = new ArrayList<Movie>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    final int x = i;  // or anything else, but you must assign it some value
    mList.add(new Movie() {
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Movie" + x;
        } 
    });
}
```

You cannot make `x` `static` - the `static` modifier is used only on the data fields (or methods) of a class. Furthermore `x` must indeed be `final` so as to allow the `toString` method of the anonymous class to access it.

Comment: Can you explain what the asker did wrong?  I feel that would make this answer more complete.